# Can a Publisher in JMS return a value?

Tags: java, jms, publish-subscribe, spring-jms

I am using JMS to publish an object into a topic. The subscriber will read the object, perform some operations and should return a value.

But from what I saw in different code, the publisher can just publish the object into a topic and it doesnt get anything back.

```
public void send(Message m){
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(topic, m);
    }



@JmsListener(destination = "${jsa.activemq.topic}")
    public void receive(Message msg){
        System.out.println("Recieved Message: " + msg);
    }
```

I need the receiver to return a value to the publisher. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template `sendAndReceive()` operations. It doesn't have `convertSendAndReceive()` methods; so you'd have to do the to/from message conversion manually (e.g. with a `SimpleMessageConverter`).

You can also use a Spring Integration [JMS Outbound Gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-outbound-gateway) as part of a Spring Integration application.

Comment: Can you point to any resources for the first method you said?

Comment: I need to get a value back from the receiver like we get when we call a method.

Comment: You do have JMSmessagingtemplate convertsendandrecieve(..,..,..) method, right? which can be used to convert ?

Comment: True. I forgot about that.